# What's the org-mode syntax that tells LaTeX to place a float /here/

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

My images are floating much more than I'd like.  I'd like to force them to be where I tell them to be more like

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{./image.png}
\end{figure}
```

What I currently have is this, which does not seem to be doing it:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: ::placement {!htb}{0.75\textwidth}
[[./image.png]]
```

What's the correct syntax to anchor my images where I say like exclamation point does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :placement [!htb]{0.75\textwidth}
[[./image.png]]
```

Note that the attributes are specified by a single colon followed by the name of the attribute (e.g. `:placement` or `:width`) and the value of the argument is copied verbatim into the appropriate place in the exported latex file (hence `[!htb]`, not `{!htb}`, since LaTeX figures take that specification as an option, not as an argument).

A valuable debugging technique in such cases is to export to a LaTeX file and then examine the LaTeX file in an editor (presumably emacs :-) ) to see what was produced.